# How to select a specific element in an AnglujarJS ng-repeater?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onclick, click, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am completely new to Angular, so I'm not sure what's the **proper way** to do the following: I have a repeater that generates two **tr** elements for every iteration. The second **tr** element is initially hidden. I want to show the 
second **tr** element when the first one is clicked. How do I do this with Angular?

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="student in students" ng-click="showDetails()">
        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.age }} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-hide="true">
        <td colspan="3">
            <!--  Detailed information goes here -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, you have your controller set up. Your `$scope.showDetails` method should look something like:

```
$scope.showRow = [];
$scope.showDetails = function (idx) {
    $scope.showRow[idx] = true;
}
```

And then, change `ng-hide="true"` to `ng-hide="showRow"`.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="student in students" ng-click="showDetails($index)">
        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.age }} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-hide="showRow[$index]">
        <td colspan="3">
            <!--  Detailed information goes here -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Edit: used changes suggested by @AviadP. This will take into account multiple students.

Comment: I would change `ng-click="showDetails($index)"` `ng-hide="showRow[$index]"` and `$scope.showDetails = function(idx) { $scope.showRow = $scope.showRow || {}; $scope.showRow[idx]=!$scope.showRow[idx]; }`

Comment: But showRow is a varaible and I have a list of students

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was thinking of, but is this the way that this is usually done in Angular?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's more of a preference. If you want to have two rows for every student then this sort of thing would have to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Write inside the controller

```
$scope.hideRow = true;
$scope.showDetails = function () {
    $scope.hideRow = false;
}
```

and add hideRow scope inside `ng-hide`

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="student in students" ng-click="showDetails()">
        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ student.age }} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-hide="hideRow">
        <td colspan="3">
            <!--  Detailed information goes here -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/4ggbog6u/

I provide each student an attribute to decide to show detail or not

```
  $scope.showDetails = function(index) {
      $scope.students[index].detailOn = !$scope.students[index].detailOn;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0yLk4znh/

Modified a couple of things:

`ng-hide` changed to `ng-show`

adding `showDetails` property to students

So you can hide all elements and only make visible the selected row.